# button_click; if (itemexist){update} else{add}

Tags: c#, sql, listbox

I want to checked item in `FgTxt` if he exist update `Number` in sql else add item. In google I only find information about hide all about selected item. I only want to take second item in this index in DB.

```
        loadlist();
        ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)ItemListOrder.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(TradeTxt.Text);    //it's probably bad idea but this I found and try it 
        string sitem = item.ToString();  //idk how to take info from 'item' 


        if (sitem==FgTxt.Text) 
        {
          //update
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into Conector (Item, Number) values ('" + TradeTxt.Text + "','" + NumberTrTxt.Text + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Clone();
        }
```

Comment: You should read about Sql Injection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: thanks juan ur links with wiki helped me ;>

Comment: then enjoy this one https://xkcd.com/327/